# Referencing a word in memory vs referencing a memory cell?

Tags: memory, assembly, mips, ram, memory-address

Well i probably could have asked the professor about this, but i haven't been going to faculty very often in the past few weeks so i'll ask anyone who comes across this.

In MIPS if an the starting address of an array of integers (the address of A[0]) is stored in the register $s3 then the assembler code for storing the 9th element of the array in the temporary register $t0 will be lw $t0 32($s3). So the offset is 32. The explanation for  this is that most architectures today reference every byte in memory(i.e. every memory cell) and since an integer is 4 bytes which is the most common size of a "word" the address for the next integer in memory would be the current address + 4 , making address for 9th integer: starting address + 4*8. Nice!

Now i know that for a character encoded in ASCII the number of bits needed is 8 = 1 byte. So what i want to ask is if we have an array of chars will it be the case that the next character's address in the array is: "the current address + 1" since for chat only 1 memory cell is needed and every memory cell has its own address? Or, because the word size in the architecture is 4 bytes, the smallest amount that can be referenced is a word although every memory cell has its own address, making the character take 4 byes despite only needing 1? If the first case if true how would the processor know weather to add 1 to the address of 4? Wouldn't it be needed for an additional instruction being made by the compiler for determining the data type? Also, cause the int took the space referenced by 4 addresses, is the address which the processor uses to load the integer that of the first byte or?

Now i'm on cache memory(by the way i'm learning from Patterson and Hennessy's Computer organization and design) and this thing really bothers me so i would be grateful if someone 
would answer. So, thanks!

Comment: Oh god i never thought about this

int main()
{

    int x[10];
    char a[10];
    long long p[10];
    printf("Address of x[0] = %d, and that of x[1] is %d \n", &x[0], &x[1]);
    printf("Address of a[0] = %d, and that of a[1] is %d \n", &a[0], &a[1]);
    printf("Address of p[0] = %d, and that of p[1] is %d ", &p[0], &p[1]);
}

and the result:
Address of x[0] = 2686696, and that of x[1] is 2686700
Address of a[0] = 2686686, and that of a[1] is 2686687
Address of p[0] = 2686600, and that of p[1] is 2686608

Comment: Still how would the compiler notify the processor that it needs to increment for 1 or 4? I know about Hi and Lo registers and how the processor processes data longer than a 32 bit word like long long.

Comment: Now when i think of it: the compiler doesn't need to generate an additional instruction for noting that it is a char or an int. It would read the higher level code and determine if it should set the offset x*4 or x*1. And the loading of the char, would automatically take the place of the lowest bits so the others will stay the same, so i guess if there is something in the register it should be first replaced by zeroes and then be used to store chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if we have an array of chars will it be the case that the next character's address in the array is: "the current address + 1 [byte]" ?

Yes.

> If [this] is true how would the processor know weather to add 1 to the address of 4? Wouldn't it be needed for an additional instruction being made by the compiler for determining the data type?

There *are* additional instructions. `lw` is used for loading *words*, while `lb`/`lbu` is used for loading *bytes*. But that only affects the size of the data to load. The offsets aren't scaled according to the data size like they are in C. If you use an offset of 3 for an `lw` it will try to load from the address given by the base register + *3 bytes*.

> Also, cause the int took the space referenced by 4 addresses, is the address which the processor uses to load the integer that of the first byte or?

Yes. And the layout of the word value in memory depends on the endianness of the CPU. The value 0x12345678 on a little-endian system would be stored as:

```
-- address -->
78 56 34 12
```

and on a big-endian system it would be stored as:

```
-- address -->
12 34 56 78
```

Comment: I didn't quite get the part about the offset not being scaled. Does the compiler determine the data type from the higher level program it compiles (e.g. C++) and puts the offset accordingly?